# Having trouble using Kwicks to open first li of accordion slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, accordion, kwicks

I have tried a few different methods to have the first li of the accordion slider open by default but nothing is working properly.

I have tried to add the class active but it doesn't do anything unless the inline style is set to 686px. If I add that it changes the other images as well.

I'm sure it a simple solution that I am over looking.

http://roofing.kellykruschel.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this , working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/A6XkM/)

KWICKS 2.0

```
$('.kwicks').kwicks('expand', 0);
```

KWICKS 1.5

```
 $('.kwicks').kwicks({
    size: 321,
    max : 686,
    spacing : 0,
    behavior: 'menu',
    sticky :true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I updated my code to what you had on Fiddle but when I add $('.kwicks').kwicks('expand', 0); to the javascript area the accordion stops expanding and everything stays collapsed with no javascript errors in the browser.

Comment: @Kelly Kruschel sorry my mistake, expand method is supported in 2.0 version whereas sticky is supported in 1.5 kwicks version